# Entire android app stops redrawing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using a ViewPager with four fragments. In every fragment i'm using custom made components that that inheriths from SurfaceView.

If i'm too fast to swipe or change tab when the activity is brought up front the gui freezes. Events etc are still triggered, so the gui-thread is not locked.

I can also see "ghosts" of components sometimes in the view of the intialized components when I swipe.

Does anyone have any idea of what is causing this?